# Node.js Application hosted via Plesk goes inactive over night requiring HTTP Ping to reactivate

Tags: node.js, passenger, plesk

I'm hosting a Node.js Application via the Node.js Extension provided by Plesk right now and have noticed that my application goes into an inactive state every day and requires a http call to wake up again. This is likely related to overnight updates, performed by Plesk, which require a restart of the services.

Is there away to avoid this with the Node.js Extension for Plesk other than either using a different hosting solution or creating another app that performs an http request to it every minute?

The last output in the logs states:

```
[Tue Nov 03 03:44:37.514128 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6545] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

Before that, the application was working normally.

Plesk Version: 18.0.31
Node.js Extension Version: 1.3.7-121

Comment: hey @jastend I have the same issue. Any clue'

Comment: @AlbertSunyer I ended up writing a quick ping script that's executed via PM2, pinging my app every 5 minutes. So far, I think this is the only "solution" to keep the service alive.